# Finding all possible values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

we have to find all possible prime values $(p,q,r)$ such that

$ pq = r + 1 $

$ 2(p^2+q^2) = r^2 + 1 $

I do not know how to start looking for an answer.

Comment: This seems to be a number theoretic question.

Comment: There is another approach to this: you can muitiple the first equation by two, and add the two equations together. You should get $2(p+q)^2=(r+2)^2+1$. This is equivalent to $2a^2=b^2+1$, so you have to find all $a$ such that $2a^2-1$ is a perfect square. I have found $a=1$ and $a=5$ by trial and error.

Comment: However, I don't know a proof about the number of solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the second equation we find that $r$ is odd. Hence $r+1$ is even, and one of $p$ and $q$ must be $2$. We may assume that $p=2$. Then we get $2q = r+1$ and $$8+2q^2=r^2+1=(r+1)(r-1)+2=2q(2q-2)+2,$$
implying $2q^2-4q-6=0$ or $(q-3)(q+1)=0$. This has $q=3$ as only prime solution, hence $q=3$ and $r = 2q - 1 = 5$.

In conclusion, there are two solutions: $(p,q,r)=(2,3,5)$ and $(p,q,r)=(3,2,5)$.

Comment: I don't understand, why does $p$ $have$ to be $2$? Why can't it be any multiple of $2$?

Comment: $p$, $q$, $r$ are primes